# select from two mysql tables where column value is similar and id is retrieved from previous page

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question. my english isn't well. so i hope i explain well...

i have two tables, tbl_home and tbl_office, the question is

how do i make a select statement from 2 tables which have identical value from column 'case_no' where it is referenced in both table..

```
$a=$_POST['home_id']
```

the code above is where i get the home_id from, 
while the statement below is how i try to select both tables based on value in **column** 'case_no' of both table. but it is based on variable $a which i retrieved from form

```
    <?php
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_office WHERE case_no IN (SELECT * FROM tbl_home WHERE home_id = '$
$result2=$conn->query($sql2);

         while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
         $a=$row['case_no'];
        $bc=$row['colour'];

         echo " $a <br/> ";
         echo " $bc2 <br/>";
        ?>
```

is the select statement above correct??

[image]
[image]

soo, i just want anybody to take a look a this specific statement and how to make it right

```
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_office WHERE case_no IN (SELECT * FROM tbl_home WHERE home_id = '$a'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need inner join to use:

```
   " SELECT t_office.home_id,t_office.case_no,t_office.name FROM tbl_office
    t_office INNER JOIN tbl_home t_home ON t_office.case_no = t_home.case_no;
    where t_office.case_no ='$a'";
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use "inner join"  for example:
"SELECT t.home_id,t.case_no,t.name FROM tbl_office
t INNER JOIN tbl_home h ON h.case_no = h.case_no"

Comment: ON t.case_no = h.case_no

Answer (score 0):

```
**select tbl_home.name,tbl_office.case_no,tbl_office.color from tbl_office
INNER JOIN tbl_home on tbl_office.case_no = tbl_home.case_no
where tbl_office.case_no ='$a';**
```

I hope this will be working fine until $a(case_no) value is existed in tbl_home or else it doesn't give any rows